# Loop through month and year till date while using a merge statement

Tags: sql-server, date

I have 2 tables with the following datas in them:-

Company

CompanyId CompanyName

1         Company1

2         Company2

3         Company3

Employees

EmployeeId EmployeeName CompanyId StartDate

1          Employee1        1     12/21/2011

2          Employee2        1     01/20/2012

3          Employee3        2     03/23/2012

4          Employee4        2     07/15/2012

5          Employee5        2     01/20/2013

6          Employee6        3     12/17/2013

Now i want to check, How many people were recruited in the team in the specified month and year? I have the storage table as follows:-

RecruiterIndicator

CompanyId Year Month EmployeeRecruited

1         2011 12      1

1         2012 1        1

2         2012 3        1

2         2012 7        1

2         2013 1        1

3         2013 12      1

This should be a merge stored procedure that should update the data if it is present for the same month year and company and insert if that is not present? The loop would start from a particular date that can be an parameter and it would loop through the current month.

Please help me with this

Thanks

Vishal

Comment: You have to join those 2 tables, then to apply a GROUP BY. I can give you help you after you try yourself to write some code.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT YEAR(StartDate) AS [Year], MONTH(StartDate) AS [Month], COUNT(*) EmpTotal
FROM Employees
GROUP BY YEAR(StartDate),  MONTH(StartDate)
```

If you want to see the Total Employees by company as well you can do something like this

```
SELECT YEAR(StartDate) AS [Year], MONTH(StartDate) AS [Month]
       ,C.CompanyName , COUNT(E.EmployeeId) EmpTotal
FROM Employees E INNER JOIN Company C
ON E.CompanyId = C.CompanyId
GROUP BY YEAR(StartDate),  MONTH(StartDate) ,C.CompanyName
```